# How can we show this process is an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

In my book it says that:

$X(t)=e^{-t}W(e^{2t})$

(where $t\in[0,\infty)$ and $W(t)$ is a Brownian motion) is an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. I know that $X(t)$ is a Gaussian process but how can we show that it is also an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process?

Comment: hint: write it as an sde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that
$$X(t)-X(s)e^{-(t-s)}=e^{-t}(W(e^{2t})-W(e^{2s}))\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1-e^{-2(t-s)})$$
If $X(s)$ is known the conditional distribution becomes
$$X(t)|X(s)\sim\mathcal{N}(X(s)e^{-(t-s)},1-e^{-2(t-s)})$$
If we indicate with $p(y,t|x,0)$ the Gaussian density of $X(t)|X(0)$, given the initial condition $X(0)=x\implies p(y,0|x,0)=\delta(y-x) $, it can be checked that
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial }{\partial y}(yp)+\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial y^2}$$
which is the Fokker-Planck equation of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process with mean reversion coefficient $1$ and volatility $\sqrt{2}$.